# Socket.io server crash after client reload/leave page

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a strange situation. I'm writing a web application for streaming rtsp from ip cameras. Everything is fine except when client that watches the stream reload or leave page the server crashes(not always).

**Here's the crash output:**

```
zlib.js:499
      var newReq = self._handle.write(flushFlag,
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of null
    at Zlib.callback (zlib.js:499:33)
```

**Server side:**

```
const app = require('express')();
const child_process = require('child_process');
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.of('/stream').on('connection', function(socket) {
    let room;
    socket.on('startStream', function(camuid) {
        room = camuid;
        let stream;
        socket.join(room);

        if (processes.indexOf(camuid) == -1) {
            processes.push(camuid);
            logic.Onvif.getStreamLink(camuid).then(rtsp_link => {
                stream = child_process.spawn("ffmpeg", [
                    '-y',
                    '-re',
                    "-i", rtsp_link,
                    '-f', 'mjpeg',
                    '-'
                ], {
                    detached: false
                });

                stream.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                    const frame = Object.values(new Uint8Array(data));
                    socket.nsp.to(room).emit('camfeed', frame);
                });

            }).catch((e) => {
                socket.nsp.to(room).emit('streamError', true);
            });
        }
    });
```

**On the client side:**

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
socket = io.connect(`http://${location.hostname}:8088/stream`);
socket.on('connect', function() {
   socket.emit('startStream', $this.$props.id);
});
socket.on('camfeed', function (data) {
   //Here the data is displayed on canvas
});
```

I tried to find out what part of code in the server causes that behaviour with no luck so far.

I tried put functions, listeners and emitters in `try{}catch` and `console.log` every step to see where it stops but the output is not always the same.

So I started looking for a solution and found a github issue saying that the zlib is responsible for compressing data to gzip before sending and the error is caused by trying to process data that doesn't exist. On the other hand I don't have zlib installed as a dependency and as far as I know zlib package isn't used anymore because node has this functionality built-in. I searched the `node_modules` and found minizlib package but no clue whose is that dependency.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you got any solution?

Comment: got the same issue

Comment: Ever found the solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use

```
  socket.on("disconnect",function(){
  //delete all user data here
  })
```

so it stops using the objects you created